# .Net Event on Collection Update

Tags: .net, collections

Is there a collection class of type IList or IEnumerable that has a flag I can check or event that can be triggered if the collection changes either by add, remove or update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). It implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) so you can implement that yourself or use/subclass `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes : [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604.aspx).

Actually, it implements the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface that defines the [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event (that means you can add the logic to any of your class if `ObservableCollection<T>` is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `ObservableCollection<T>` class in .Net 3.0-4.0 that exposes a `CollectionChanged` event which would work for what you want.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` has been in the framework since .Net 3.0.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. Although, technically I'm not wrong because it IS in 4.0 ;) Editing my answer to reflect framework versions.